# Why is the PowerShell SetEnvironmentVariable command deleting the existing variable?

Tags: windows, powershell

**Good-day all,**

I've written a PowerShell function to help me update a System Environment Variable on a bunch of Windows 7 and 10 Enterprise machines.  I've noticed, however, that my **"[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()"** command is deleting the existing variable and not changing its value - like I'm expecting it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
$ComputerName = "SERVER1"
$MyEnvVar = "C:\Some_Path\"

ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName){

    $Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 2 -Quiet

    If ($Online -eq $True){
        $OldValue = Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariableName","Machine")}
        Write-Host "Old Value is: $OldValue"
        Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable","$MyEnvVar","Machine")}
        $NewValue = Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariableName","Machine")}
        Write-Host "New Value is: $NewValue"

    }
}
```

Comment: `$MyEnvVar` is evaluated in the context of the remote machine rather than your local value. Use `$using:MyEnvVar` to remote it.

Comment: Do I do that when I'm declaring $MyEnvVar or when I'm using it in the Set command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
  Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable","$MyEnvVar","Machine")}
```

to:

```
 Invoke-Command $Computer -ScriptBlock {[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable",$Using:MyEnvVar,"Machine")}
```

From [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6):

> Example 5: Using a Local Variable in a Remote Command
>
> For variables in a remote command created in the local session, use the Using scope modifier. PowerShell assumes that the variables in remote commands were created in the remote session.

Also checkout [about_remote_variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6).

Comment: That worked like a charm and I've learned something new in the process, thank you.